# Any alternatives to the "connection" string when using azure storage python client library?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I am about to write my first python program to read/write remote azure storage blob (block blob).
I did some research. It is as if the storage "connection string" is absolutely mandatory. In another word, the Microsoft client-side python library requires a "connection-string" created by the storage account in order to gain access to the remote blob.

In order to keep everything as simple as possible, I am hoping that I can write a small python code to invoke an HTTP GET/PUT method (for accessing the remote azure blob storage resource) without touching the "connection string" generated by the storage account. Yet, it doesn't seem to be possible after reading Microsoft storage documentation.

Can anyone make any comment to shed any light?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could not connect to azure storage blob without any keys. Several methods for you to connect Azure storage blob:

1. Connection string

2. Account name and account key

3. Azure AD access token

4. SAS token

Comment: That is what I thought until I took a look at Microsoft storage python client library. Their Document and example specify that I need to provide the "connection string" in order to make the connection. Not a word about the other 3 alternatives such as SAS. Maybe I should look more closely. Do you know where I can obtain some example about writing a python client program using SAS to access remote azure blob? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAS token is generated by account_name and account_key. Both them are in the connection string too.

**With SAS token:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, generate_account_sas, ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions

sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name="<storage-account-name>",
    account_key="<account-access-key>",
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(service=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<my_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net", credential=sas_token)
```

---

So you could access with Azure AD Access token based on service principal.

**With Azure AD Access token:**

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.common import TokenCredential

TENANT_ID = "xxxxxx"
CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxx"
CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxx"
RESOURCE = "https://storage.azure.com/"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT_ID,
    secret = CLIENT_SECRET,
    tenant = TENANT_ID,
    resource = RESOURCE
) 
token_credential = TokenCredential(credentials.token["access_token"])

ACCOUNT_NAME = "pamelastorage123"
CONTAINER_NAME = "pamelac"
blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, token_credential=token_credential)
blob = blobService.get_blob_to_text(CONTAINER_NAME, "test.txt")
print(blob.content)
```

Note: plz follow these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet) to assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role and register an application first.

For more information about authentication, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-python#authentication).

Comment: Thump-up. I will definitely dive into it. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: From the above SAS example, it calls the generate_account_sas to generate the SAS dynamically. Can I use SAS generated by the Azure portal?. Instead of generating the SAS programmingly, can I use the SAS copied from the Azure portal. In another word, can I cretae the SAS manually ? Thanks,

Comment: Obviously yes, you could use the SAS in the portal.

Comment: This is working without needing to create TokenCredential. We can pass ServicePrincipalCredentials directly.